# Different behaviour of mouse over for top bar menu on stackexchange.com and other sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, top-bar

On the most of Stack Exchange sites you need to make a click/tap on the menu item in the top bar if you want to open it:

> [image: MSE]

But on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) it works without clicking/tapping if any menu is already opened:

> [image: SE]

Why not to make such behavior consistent?

Comment: @Joe Which version?

Comment: @Catija Top one. We would need to do additional work to get the bottom one without reintroducing [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343136#343136).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kasra fixed this up earlier today and the fix is now live.

Unfortunately, as much as we would prefer to go with the bottom version where hover works, we have to stick with the top click-required approach for now to avoid reintroducing [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343136#343136).

Comment: Is there mod menu at all in se.com?

Comment: @ShadowWizard even if there is no mod menu, behaviour should be the same on the whole Network.

Comment: @alexolut but the reasoning Adam gave is to avoid the bug, which appears to be related to the top bar diamond only.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not sure. You can move cursor diagonally through any menu item, not only mod, if I understood the bug clearly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard alexolut is correct. It's not the mod menu that's the issue, it's that moving diagonally can pretty easily trigger dialogs to the left of the one you're actually trying to use.